# Contacts in circles are invisible in Phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, contacts, hardware, google-plus

I have a Moto G ver1 running Android 4.4.4
After the last update I noticed that any contact that is also added to  G+ circles is NOT searchable on the phone. If I search by phone number the contacts appear. If I search by name they do not. This problem affects only contacts that are added in circles. Does anybody have a solution? Thanks!

[update]

I just noticed that the problem with those contacts is the contact's name (on my phone) being different than the name of the google+ profile. If I search the profile name the contacts display correctly.